# Developing a personal blog with MVC 4 from scratch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, database-design, blogs, vs-web-site-project

I want to develop a personal blogging website using ASP.NET MVC 4.

I know that I could be using WordPress/ Joomla/ Orchard/ Umbraco/ Funnelweb, etc., instead of reinventing the wheel but I really wish to try it out myself.

I do not want my website to look like some beatle-aged archaic remain. I see plugins like Akismet/ Prettify/ Markdown/ nrelate that add amazing functionalities to your blog. But I am not really sure if I would be able to use any of these in my custom application as most of them are PHP based. I want to stick under the Microsoft roof and implement technologies like HTML5, CSS3 Silverlight5 and WCF 4.0, along with ASP.NET MVC 4. (At least thats what I plan to do)

I understand that I need to develop a scalable database design that could accomodate newer functionalities in the future. Additionally, the exorbitant focus on SEO and cross-browser capabilities is overwhelming. Permanent links for individual blogs, internal navigation, video-embedding inside posts, etc., sound like building Rome in a day

Please if you could guide me personally or direct me to appropriate resources, it would be very helpful.

Comment: http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/12/how_to_create_a_simple_blog_part1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sort of doing it right now on my own. It's not done yet but it will give you an idea: [MvcBloggy](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/MvcBloggy).

Also, have a look at [FunnelWeb](https://bitbucket.org/FunnelWeb/dev/src) source code. It's written in C# and uses ASP.NET MVC 3 I believe but it's a really good resource and easy to follow.

Comment: FunnelWeb was my best bet too. Going through the structure now. Thank you.